# How to break out of a do-while style loop in Rust?

Tags: rust

Rust allows a kind of do-while loop eg:

So the C style:

```
do {
    something();
} while (test());
```

Can be written in Rust as:

```
while {
    something();
    test()
}{}
```

However there is a problem using break in this case:

So this C style:

```
do {
    if (something()) {
        break;
    }
} while (test());
```

Can't be written in Rust as:

```
while {
    if (something()) {
        break;
    }
    test()
}{}
```

Fails to compile with `cannot break outside of a loop`.

Is there a way to break out of this form of while loop?

---

**Note 1)** the reason to use:
`do {...} while test()` flow control instead of
`while test() {...}` is in this case `test()` will be `false` when entering the loop initially.

**Note 2)** When using  `while {...}` flow control: calling `continue` in the body of the code will skip the `break` check at the end.

See related question: [How to wrap a do-while style loop in a macro, maintaining 'continue' flow control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40367127)

Comment: Why not `loop { /* code */ if test() { break; } }` ?

Comment: I have to say I think this is a horrible hack ([link for those who haven't seen it before](https://gist.github.com/huonw/8435502)). The first set of braces aren't actually the while loop body - they're the **condition**, which is why you can't break out. `while { break } {}` doesn't make any sense, which is why this syntax is probably more harmful than helpful.

Comment: @Neikos, When the loop is defined in a macro, with the code body passed in as an argument, using `continue` causes a non-obvious infinite loop, since the break never runs.

Comment: @Aurora0001 One man's hack is another man's pattern. :) I've seen this style used in various Lisp dialects that lacked native do-while (e.g. Emacs Lisp), and it's readable once you get used to it. I would agree that, once `break` and `continue` become needed, that it is probably a better idea to switch to `loop` with custom-placed break logic.

Comment: @user4815162342, perhaps so, but in my opinion it's much better to be 'defensive' and assume that the programmer reading your code isn't as smart as you, and won't notice the pattern. I definitely wouldn't have known what was happening without it being pointed out and thinking about it.

Comment: Clearly this isn't something to use for the common case to write readable code. Better use these kinds of tricks like `unsafe`, its last resort when there are no better options. And after looking into this, it seems like there probably are better options nearly every time.

Comment: @Aurora0001 I agree about defensiveness - as they say, "write code as if the next maintainer is a lunatic who knows where you live."  On the other hand, some very useful idioms look like garbage when first encountered, but one learns to recognize, use, and even appreciate them after a while. (Rust has its fair share of features that look strange at first, such as the use of `;` to determine whether a value is returned.) Rust is still a young language, and it remains to be seen which patterns will be judged sufficiently useful by the community to be recognized as idioms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid solution close to your proposition could be:

```
while {
    // bloc
    test()
} {
    // break conditions belonging here
    if (something()) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Some remarks:

- The first bracket has to be an expression, Rust allows the user to write statements before it and the whole `bloc` with `test()` is considered as an expression but there are some limitations as you have pointed out
- A well built loop generally avoids break and continue statements, this solution has the advantage to separates the loop-flow logic in the first bracket from the added control logic exceptionally used in the second bracket as it were parameters of the loop outside of it
- this time something() is called after test(), it means that it won't be able to break the first iteration of the loop

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments, it is important to understand how this pattern works. It is not a special form of `while`, it simply abuses the loop test to do things normally done in the body. Since `break` and `continue` don't belong in the loop test (unless the loop is part of another loop, in which case they will compile, but break/continue the *outer* loop), Rust rejects them.

A straightforward way to emulate `break` with the above pattern is by moving the test code to a closure from which one can exit with `return`:

```
while (|| {
    if something() {
        return false // break
    }
    test()
})() {}
```

`continue` can be emulated the same way, simply by returning `true` from the closure.

It would probably possible to make the intention clearer if this were expressed as a macro.

Answer (score 3):

With rust you can label a loop when you declare it and use the label to break the loop later:

```rust
'mylabel: loop {
  something();
  if test() { break 'mylabel; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are overthinking this.

Let's build a truth table:

```
+-------------+--------+--------+
| something() | test() | Result |
+-------------+--------+--------+
|    true     |  true  |  stop  |
+-------------+--------+--------+
|    true     |  false |  stop  |
+-------------+--------+--------+
|    false    |  true  |  go on |
+-------------+--------+--------+
|    false    |  false |  stop  |
+-------------+--------+--------+
```

Thus, this can be written as:

```
while !something() && test {}
```

There is no need for a `break`.

Comment: The reason I can't use this logic is `test` is false when entering the loop for the first time, added this as a note in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you force a `break` into the condition block, when returning `false` would make it much clearer to terminate the while loop?
Also, this solution doesn't change the program logic: `something()` is still executed before `test()`.

```
while {
    if something() {
        false  // break
    } else {
        test()
    }
} {}
```