# How to wrap a do-while style loop in a macro, maintaining 'continue' flow control?

Tags: macros, rust

In Rust, a do-while style loop can be written:

```
loop {
    something();

    if !test() {
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that the purpose of using the do-while form instead of `while test() { something() }`, is that `test()` may need to run *after* `something()`.

This works, but when the logic is wrapped in a macro, it's less obvious what happens when `continue` is used. It will skip the test, potentially entering an infinite loop:

```
macro_rules! loop_over_items {
    ($item:expr, $iter:ident, $code:block) => {
        {
            let first = $item.first;
            let mut $iter = first;
            loop {
                $code
                $iter = $iter.next;
                if (first != $iter) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works in a basic case:

```
loop_over_items!(item, iter_elem, {
    code_to_run;
});
```

But this may enter an infinite loop which isn't very obvious at first glance:

```
loop_over_items!(item, iter_elem, {
    if some_test() {
        continue;
    }
    code_to_run;
});
```

What would be a good method in Rust to write a macro that supports use of `continue` skipping the logic after `$code`?

Comment: Why is this question marked to close as: `Questions seeking debugging help`, this is a general question about flow control (with answers showing how it can be done).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on the idea in [ideasman42's own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40367252/1600898), the logic of executing a loop iteration while testing whether it contained `break` or `continue` can itself be encapsulated in a macro:

```
enum LoopIteration {
    Normal,
    Break,
    Continue,
}

macro_rules! exec_iteration {
    ($code: block) => {{
        let mut _state = LoopIteration::Normal;
        loop {
            if let LoopIteration::Break = _state {
                // got back here after having preparing for break - it
                // means a continue happened
                _state = LoopIteration::Continue;
                break;
            }
            // prepare for break
            _state = LoopIteration::Break;
            $code;
            // neither break nor continue occurred
            _state = LoopIteration::Normal;
            break;
        }
        _state
    }}
}
```

With that in place, a general do-while macro with support for `break` and `continue` can be written as follows:

```
macro_rules! do_while {
    ($code: block, $test: expr) => {{
        loop {
            match exec_iteration!($code) {
                LoopIteration::Normal => (),
                LoopIteration::Break => break,
                LoopIteration::Continue => continue,
            }

            if !$test {
                break;
            }
        }
    }}
}
```

The above is not very useful because we could have simply embedded the `$code` in the loop with the same effect. But when implementing a macro like `loop_over_items`, there is now a way to move to the next item after `$code` even if it uses `continue`:

```
macro_rules! loop_over_items {
    ($item:expr, $iter:ident, $code:block) => {{
        let first = $item.first;
        let mut $iter = first;
        loop {
            if let LoopIteration::Break = exec_iteration!($code) {
                break
            }
            // Advance the iterator before proceeding, even if
            // "continue" was used
            $iter = $iter.next;
            if first != $iter {
                break;
            }
        }
    }}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this answer to show it's possible to detect continue/break within an unknown code-block, however it's not *pretty*.

```
macro_rules! loop_over_items {
    ($item:expr, $iter:ident, $code:block) => {
        {
            let first = $item.first;
            let mut $iter = first;
            loop {

                {
                    let mut loop_state = false;
                    loop {
                        if loop_state == true {
                            break;  // continue found in 'code'
                        }
                        loop_state = false;
                        $code
                        if loop_state {}  // quiet unused warning
                        loop_state = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    if loop_state == false {
                        break;  // break in 'code'
                    }
                }

                $iter = $iter.next;
                if (first != $iter) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Note, I'm curious to know some impacts of using this method:

- Are break/continue checks are optimized away in the case they aren't used in the `body` passed into the macro *(it should be possible)*.
- When the logic to detect break/continue applies - is it roughly as efficient as using continue/break in a while loop *(the do-while style means its not going to be exactly the same)*.
- When break/continue isn't used in the code-block, these checks are optimized out entirely for release builds, so this macro can be used without adding unnecessary overhead.

[See real-world use of this example.](https://gitlab.com/ideasman42/bmesh-rs/blob/master/intern/bmesh/src/bmesh_iter_macros.rs)

Comment: A brilliant idea. I've posted an answer that extracts the not-pretty testing to a separate macro, allowing for a reasonably readable definition of `loop_over_items`.